Malfunctioning voltage output in PIC16F84A
Issue
When I try to input voltage on a digital pin, 0V is applied.
Goal
5V is applied to the digital pin.
Environment

PIC16F84A
MPLAB X IDE v6.20
C language
Windows 11

Diagram

The source voltage is 5V.
Code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>

#pragma config CP = OFF, PWRTE = ON, WDTE = OFF

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    TRISA1 = 0x00;
    while(1) {
        RA1 = 1;
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

The voltage applied to RA1 was 0. I also tried RB0 but I got 0.34V. I used a resistor instead of an led to simplify the problem.
How I tried to solve the error
I googled "PIC16F84A LED" and checked the first 10 pages in vain.
Your advices will be appreciated.
2024-08-02 Edit
I updated my circuit and code according to the answer by @Spehro Pefhany but the output of RA0 was 0V.
Circuit

Code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>

#pragma config CP = OFF, PWRTE = ON, WDTE = OFF, FOSC = HS
#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    TRISA0 = 0x00;

    while(1){
        RA0 ^= 1;
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}

What should I do next?
2024-06-04 Edit
I found out that the voltage is applied to RB1. When I connect an LED to it, it flashes.I remember set the output port to it but I'm sure I overrode it to RA0. Besides, I got an error message.

Failed to program device The preserve memory range(s) string entered
on the "Memories to Program" property page is empty.

Do you have any advice?

Did you flash the config bits in addition to just flashing the program to memory?

I didn't know what "flashing the config bits" meant but at least I clicked Buildi For Debuggng and Make and Program Device and got the following; The following memory area(s) will be programmed:
program memory: start address = 0x0, end address = 0x3ff
configuration memory
Programming/Verify complete

Time traveling in the date? Anyway, heading states problem with output, question states problem with input. Which is it?

The former. I'd like 5V on my output pin.

The diagram you show has no clock components, that alone is enough to keep it from doing anything. The configuration choices are:
• LP Low Power Crystal
• XT Crystal/Resonator
• HS High Speed Crystal/Resonator
• RC Resistor/Capacitor
They are set with a #pragma entry for FOSC1/FOSC0
Each choice requires external components or an external clock signal source.
Later chips (the PIC16F84A is ancient) often have internal RC clocks, and a LOT more things that should be configured or initialized.
